# How to add app.config transform to a 4.8 Azure WebJob (.NET Framework) in VS 2022?

Tags: app-config, visual-studio-2022, azure-webjobs, .net-4.8, config-transformation

After creating a project using `Azure WebJob (.NET Framework)` template with 4.8.1 in `VS2022`, `app.config` transformations do not appear to be supported.  The right-click to add the transform is not available. Also, hacking the csproj file to arrange transforms that are "DependentUpon" the `app.config` results in the correct appearance in the Solution Explorer, but build, debugging and publish do not result in any transformation taking place.

Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 (64-bit) Version 17.4.4

Has anyone achieved this?

Answer (score 1):

I have created `Azure WebJob` with `.Net Framework 4.8`.

Even I am unable to find the option to `Add the Transform`.

[image]

- We have `SlowCheetah` Package to Transform `xml` and `json` files at build time based on the Configuration.
- Close the `Visual Studio` before downloading the Package, to complete the download fast.
- Download the `SlowCheetah` Package, restart the `Visual Studio`.

[`SlowCheetah`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscps.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms) for `VS 2017 - 2019`.

[`SlowCheetah`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscps.SlowCheetah-XMLTransforms-VS2022) for `VS 2022`.

- I have Downloaded Package for `VS 2022`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

- Now I am able to see the option to `Add Transform`.

[image]

[image]

- Click on `Yes` to continue.
- `app.Debug.config` and `app.Release.config` got added below the `app.config` file.

[image]